# Can Views output clean URLs from titles with quotes, and other special chars?

Tags: 7, views, uri

I have a view that really needs some nice clean URLs; the links are the titles of the content items in the view.

I am pretty sure I have been able to clean up URLs with views before (I could be wrong though), but I just can't seem to find it today.
Removing spaces is simple enough but I need more.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading nodes they will already have a path associated with them. Assuming you have setup path aliases (url aliases), and potentially url patterns with the pathauto module) for these nodes there will already be a field (Content: Path). This field will contain a clean and tidy url you can add which will give you the path to these nodes.  If you just want the node title to be linked to itself there is an option to 'Link this field to the original piece of content' when you add 'Content: Title'.

tl;dr Try to keep this stuff out of Views and add the relevant fields that are already available.

Comment: George. Do you know if there are any special tokens available site wide to get the clean url. I am having trouble getting my comment count field in my View to give a correct path.